# Dict values not showing in sorted order python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, loops, return-value

I have a for loop where I am iterating through values and comparing them from  two json files. When I print out the values, I am checking to see if the key 'File Name' has a match between two of the files. The order of the data has been swapped but the values are the same. They have not changed.

```
dave.json has a match 

emhy.json has no match 

same.json has no match
```

I have tried to use `sorted()` to print it out in ascending order but it still does not seem to work. My JSON files are as follows:

```
day.json
{"File Name": "dave.json", "File Size": 2800}
{"File Name": "same.json", "File Size": 600}
{"File Name": "emhy.json", "File Size": 600}

night.json 
{"File Name": "dave.json", "File Size": 2800}
{"File Name": "emhy.json", "File Size": 600}
{"File Name": "same.json", "File Size": 600}
```

The order of the values is still the same. My code so far is as follows:

```
def compare_files():

    with open('day.json', 'r') as current_data_file, open('night.json',
                                                                     'r') as pre_data_file:

           for current_data, previous_data in zip(current_data_file, pre_data_file):

        data_current = json.loads(current_data)
        data_previous = json.loads(previous_data)
        sorted_previous = sorted(data_previous.items() , key = lambda t: t[0])
        sorted_current = sorted(data_current.items(), key=lambda t: t[0])
        current_fn = data_current['File Name']
        previous_fn = data_previous['File Name']



        if sorted_previous == sorted_current:

            print (str(sorted_previous) + " has a match \n")

        elif sorted_previous != sorted_current:

            print (str(sorted_previous) + " has no match \n")





result = compare_files()
```

Comment: but the lines aren't sorted. So it only sorts the 2 keys in the dictionaries.

Comment: what you show as json files are not valid json. I guess they are in json array?

Comment: so i would need to sort lines out in my files ? @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: The files are exactly in the format i have shown them. They are dictionaries @buran

Comment: @buran He's not loading the files directly via json; he's reading each line via normal file i/o and then calling json.loads() on the line.

Comment: @john-gordon, yes I see that and that's the problem with their code - they sort each row separately by key ('FileName'  always before F'ileSize'). yet the files are named day.json and night.json even if they are not valid json:-)

Comment: Should i be loading the files directly @JohnGordon

Comment: That seems like a simpler way to do it, yes.  However then you have the problem that your files aren't proper json.

Comment: Could you refer me to some example or write some code to explain @JohnGordon

Comment: The files contain three separate dictionaries -- you'd have to contain them all within a list.  Something like `[ {dict1}, {dict2], {dict3} ]`

Comment: so contain them in a list and then sort them out in order @JohnGordon

Comment: Please extract a [mcve], so anyone can just take your code and reproduce the problem. Doing so, remove anything not necessary, often including file IO or user IO.

Answer (score 0):

First problem - your day.json and night.json are not json files, even if the name suggest they are.

Due to first problem you are not able to load them directly. You load and sort each row separately by key and compare with the respective row from the other file. 'File Name' comes always before "File Size'. And if the order is not the same in night.json and day.json file you come with incorrect results.

Third problem is you look for files in both and files in new, but not in old data. What if there is file in old, but missing in new?

If the files are in this format here is what I would do

day.json

```
{"File Name": "dave.json", "File Size": 2800}
{"File Name": "same.json", "File Size": 600}
{"File Name": "emhy.json", "File Size": 600}
{"File Name": "john.json", "File Size": 600}
```

night.json

```
{"File Name": "jane.json", "File Size": 2800}
{"File Name": "dave.json", "File Size": 2800}
{"File Name": "emhy.json", "File Size": 600}
{"File Name": "same.json", "File Size": 600}
```

python code

```
import json

def parse_file(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        return [json.loads(line)['File Name'] for line in f]

new_data = set(parse_file('day.json'))
old_data = set(parse_file('night.json'))

files_both = new_data.intersection(old_data) # files present in both
files_only_old = old_data.difference(new_data) # files in old, but not in new
files_only_new = new_data.difference(old_data) # files in new, but not in old

print(files_both) # {'emhy.json', 'dave.json', 'same.json'}
print(files_only_old) # {'jane.json'}
print(files_only_new) # {'john.json'}
```

output

```
{'emhy.json', 'dave.json', 'same.json'}
{'jane.json'}
{'john.json'}
```